# If I have OpenGL ES 2.0, do I also have 1.0?

Tags: opengl-es

I have Win 7 64.  Open GL 2.0.  In working with the Android download, Dalvik, etc., I apparently also have OpenGL ES 2.0.

An Imagine Technology emulator also has this to say about what it sees on my system:

```
PVRVFrameSetGlesLibraryPath: C:\my_dir\Bin\libGLES_CM.dll
PVRVFrameSetGlesv2LibraryPath: C:\my_dir\Bin\libGLESv2.dll
vendor/shl: Imagination Technologies (Host GL: `ATI Technologies Inc.`)
vendor/shl: OpenGL ES 1.1 ( SDK build: 2.06.26.0641)2.1.8304 Release`)
bufek withs es1 exts: OGLES1 EXTENSIONS: GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_po
int GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compress
ed_paletted_texture GL_OES_point_sprite GL_OES_point_size_array GL_OES_matrix_pa
lette GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_query_matrix GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_
compression_pvrtc GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar GL_
OES_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_OES_blend_subtract GL_OES_blend_func_separate GL_
OES_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_stencil_wrap GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette G
L_OES_stencil8 GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_texture_cube_map GL_OES_c
ompressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_OES_fra
mebuffer_object
vendor/shl: Imagination Technologies (Host GL: `ATI Technologies Inc.`)
vendor/shl: OpenGL ES 2.0 ( SDK build:  2.06.26.0641) 2.1.8304 Release`)
vendor/shl: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 ( Host GL: `1.20`)
Success.
Success.
```

My question is, do I have OpenGL ES **1.0** and **1.1** and **2.0** available to me?  All three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes and no, the emulator is providing GL ES emulation, it's not available directly in your system. But inside the emulator you have GL ES 1.0/1.1 and GL ES 2.0.